# ¿Cuales son los prefijos CSS3 que en la actualidad aun se requieren para algunas propiedades?

Tags: css3

He agregado el paquete `auto-prefixer` a mi editor de código `atom`, para que me inserte todos los prefijos correspondientes de las propiedades css3 de forma automática.

Pero mi duda viene a raíz de que solo me agrega el prefijo `-webkit-`, y según recuero hasta hace unos años se debía agregar:

> **-moz-** para Firefox, **-o-** para Opera y **-ms-** para Internet Explorer (Safari y Chrome funcionaban con **webkit**).

No sé si el `autoprefixer` está limitado (me está obviando los otros prefijos que necesito), o si actualmente ya no se requieren de los otros prefijos.

Debo presentar una web y me no quiero que si dejo solo el `webkit` en otros navegadores y sus diferentes versiones no se vean correctamente mis animaciones.

En esta web ([auto-prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io)), que agrega los prefijos online cuando insertas un código, también solo me agrega `webkit`. Pero quiero estar bien seguro que solo con ese prefijo bastará para cubrir todo.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes configurado *auto-prefixer*? Me temo que va a depender de eso.

Comment: Solo lo he instalado. Pero fíjate que en esa página que he puesto allá arriba, cuando copias tu código tampoco te agregan los otros prefijos, solo en webkit, tal y como está haciendo autoprefixer en mi atom. Osea que no sé si es una carencia de ellos (de los de autoprefixer, porque esa página también pertenece a ellos) o si actualmente ya no se usa más que el webkit. Prueba en la página por favor.

Comment: Creo que no está actualizada la página, porque cuando agrego la propiedad Box-sizing me pone el prefijo, pero, en otros sitios web dicen que ya no es necesario agregarle prefijo a esa propiedad. Ejemplo: http://shouldiprefix.com  (ahi dice que box-sizing no necesita prefijo)

Comment: Pues entonces es un tema de la configuración. Por defecto, *auto-prefixer* solo da cobertura a navegadores con un mínimo de uso (no recuerdo ahora el porcentaje). Por ejemplo, desde Firefox 14 creo que ya no es necesario usar `-moz`, y el porcentaje de personas que usa versiones más antiguas de ese navegador es tan reducido que por defecto no se tiene en cuenta. Prueba a cambiar la configuración.

Comment: ¿pero entonces ya no se sirve --o-- ni --ms--? Solo webkit y moz??

Comment: Depende de las propiedades y la configuración del autoprefixer. Si tienes, por ejemplo, puesto que soporte las dos últimas versiones de los navegadores habrá muchas propiedades a las que no añada ningún prefijo o quizá solo `webkit` que en algunas propiedades lo usan incluso navegadores con otro motor.

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia la misma duda y creo que no es necesario añadirle mas prefijos. Yo probé añadiendo otro atributo a parte del box-sizing:
{

```
 background: linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 10%, white);
 box-sizing: border-box
```

}

y me muestra esto:

{

```
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(10%, #e3e3e3), to(white));

 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 10%, white);

 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 10%, white);

 background: linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 10%, white);
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box
```

}

Entiendo que los navegadores actuales reconocen el atributo box-sizing o el prefijo webkit, pero en el caso de Opera y el linear-gradient, necesita su prefijo -o-
Soy nuevo en esto, así que... no me hagáis mucho caso  :)